# Interesting line integral using green's theorem

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Find $$\int_C \frac{2x^3+2xy^2-2y}{ x^2+y^2} \, dx+\frac{2y^3+2x^2y+2x}{ x^2+y^2} \, dy$$

Where $C$ is any simple closed loop which contains the origin.

---

#### What I figured out

I cannot use the direct version of Green's theorem.

I know that there is another version of greens theorem which is as follows :
$$\oint_{C+S} P \,dx + Q\,dy  = \iint_D \left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} \right)dA,$$
where $C$ and $S$ are oriented opposite to each other and $D$ is the region enclosed between the two loops.

Using that I found
\begin{align*}
\int_{C+S} \left( 2x-\frac{2y}{ x^2+y^2}\right) \, dx+\left(2y+\frac{2x}{ x^2+y^2} \right) \, dy
&= \iint_D \left[\left(2+\frac{4xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \right)-\left(2-\frac{4xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \right) \right]dA \\
&=\iint_D \frac{8xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2} dA
\end{align*}

---

The region inside any closed loop can be defined in polar coordinates as $$\{(r, \theta)\in D \mid 0\leq r\leq r(\theta), \, 0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi \}$$

In polar coordinates the integral becomes $$ =\iint_D \frac{8xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2} dA = \int_0^{2\pi}\!\!\int_0^{r(\theta)} \frac{4\sin2\theta}{r} dr\,d\theta $$

Oops, I am again stuck; it's not zero.

Comment: I figured it out, if any one got interested he can ask on it. What i figured out is that the integral i found in last step is zero about any closed loop. I converted this into polar coordinates, if anyone has a better solution, pls contribute

Comment: i am stuck, can any smart ass help me

Comment: It's reasonable that you obtain 0: you have to take into account that your 0 is the sum of the integrals on the two components of your boundary. You're result is the sum of the integrations on two contours around the origin with opposite orientations: since the integration does not depend on the simple closed loop you choose the two contribution are equal in modulus but with opposite sign (due to different orientations).

Answer (score 2):

You can write your integral as
$$2\int_{C} \left(-\frac{y}{ x^2+y^2}dx+\frac{x}{ x^2+y^2}dy \right) + \int_{C} \left( 2x\ dx + 2y\ dy\right)\ ,$$
the second form is exact, so its contribution is 0, while for the first for you can  do the following. Note that $$\left(-\frac{y}{ x^2+y^2}dx+\frac{x}{ x^2+y^2}dy \right) =d\ \arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\ ,$$
which in polar coordinates can be written as $d\theta$. Your integral is thus just
$$-2\int_{C} d\theta = \mp 4\pi$$
where the sign depend on the orientation of the curve you choose: $-$ if it's counterclockwise, $+$ if clockwise.

Comment: i get you idea for thee first part but not for the second part, why is it 0 !

Comment: You can see $2x\ dx+2y\ dy$ as $d\left(x^2+y^2\right)$, which in polar coordinates becomes $dr^{2}=2rdr$, so $$\int_{C} \left( 2x\ dx + 2y\ dy\right)=2\int_{C}rdr\ .$$ If you integrate on a circle of fixed radius this integral is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Green's theorem fails here because it requires $P$ and $Q$ to be differentiable in the domain $C$. Now here when $$P=\frac{2x^3+2xy^2-2y}{ x^2+y^2}$$, it is not even continuous in $(0,0)$. Since if limit exists at (0,0) then $$\lim_{y \to 0}p(0,y)=\lim_{y \to 0}\frac{-2y}{y^2}$$, which doesn't exist. It is not even bounded.

Comment: I know that green's theorem fails, but the other version  of green's theorem works